# Mismatch range error on IFS even though the data pool and logic remains the same

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to get a table of values to filter a query using 2 parameters. I set up the function using IFS() to try for logical expressions as a switch statement to behave in a UI friendly way.

The expressions each work on their own with an IF() statement. So I'm not sure why it isn't working for IFS().

The error says:
"IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 9, column count: 13."

Here is a more readable version of the formula

```
=IFS(
    AND(ISBLANK(B2), ISBLANK(B1)), 
        ARRAYFORMULA(ItemsByClassAndLevel), 
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)), ISBLANK(B2)), 
        QUERY(ItemsByClassAndLevel,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M WHERE LOWER(B) CONTAINS '"&B1&"'"),
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),ISBLANK(B1)), 
        QUERY(ItemsByClassAndLevel,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M WHERE LOWER(A) CONTAINS '"&B2&"'"), 
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)), NOT(ISBLANK(B2))),  
    QUERY(ItemsByClassAndLevel,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M WHERE LOWER(A) CONTAINS '"&B2&"' OR LOWER(B) CONTAINS '"&B1&"'")
    )
```

Here is a usable one
`=IFS(AND(ISBLANK(B2), ISBLANK(B1)), ARRAYFORMULA(ItemsByClassAndLevel), AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)), ISBLANK(B2)), QUERY(ItemsByClassAndLevel,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M WHERE LOWER(B) CONTAINS '"&B1&"'"), AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),ISBLANK(B1)), QUERY(ItemsByClassAndLevel,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M WHERE LOWER(A) CONTAINS '"&B2&"'"), AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B1)), NOT(ISBLANK(B2))), QUERY(ItemsByClassAndLevel,"SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M WHERE LOWER(A) CONTAINS '"&B2&"' OR LOWER(B) CONTAINS '"&B1&"'"))`

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and an example of a successful outcome.